# why does my background color override some of my other components?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I try to make a background color and i learn some youtube video about how do i do it. I wanted to make a gray background that was placed behind all the components, but what happened was that the background color actually overlaid some of my components.[overlap background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrjpC.png)